# Rotation problem with Action Constraint

Tags: rigging, constraints

I would like to trigger an action that I created earlier on a bone (Drumhit on the upper arm bone of a drummer).
The action would be triggered by another bone of another armature (snare on Drumcontrol) that rotates on the x axis.
The problem is as soon as I set up the Action constraint it rotates the bone. The action still works but it starts in a totally wrong position.
Can anyone please help me with this?

[image]
Here is the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r0wBDRb70z24FBue6z9qw0epDHmXOihz

Answer (score 1):

In the *Dopesheet*, you need to check the action you're using in this *Action* constraint for the *UpperArm* bone, it is called *DrumHit*.

As you can see its first rotation keyframe is NOT set to W/X/Y/Z values of 1/0/0/0, but 0.721/-0.654/etc, that's why as soon as you enable the constraint it jumps to this angle.

So what you need to do is to change this first frame rotation setting to 1/0/0/0.

Also I don't know why your *Snare*, which is supposed to be the controller bone (*Target*), had a driver, so I deleted it for my test, otherwise it couldn't move.

Now when you rotate it on the X axis, it works.

[image]